# How can i create a custom command with a custom response in Ok Google?

Tags: command, response, google-assistant-sdk

I want to implement a custom command with a custom response for my Google Home. During my researches, i found these two ways:

- Ifttt
- DialogFlow

Using Ifttt, I only found the way to create a custom command and trigger then a Webhook. This works fine - so for example if i would say "Ok Google, do whatever...", a webhook is called.

The problem is, that I'm not able to create a custom response from the webhook (e.g. Today it's Tuesday and you look really awesome today...).

Using DailogFlow, I only found the possibiliy to trigger "Ok Google, talk to Whatever". Then I'm in a dialogflow - which works find but I don't want this. I don't want to be in a dialog - I just want a straight answer from a webservice.

Is there any way to do a direct answer like "Ok Google, tell me a joke?"?